# use rosdep install rviz and get error: Missing resource rviz

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ros

platform info:

ubuntu 18.04 ros:melodic

```
(base) lzw@lzw-OptiPlex-7060:~/software/ceres-bin-2.0.0$ rosdep install rviz

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query Missing resource rviz
```

Answer (score 0):

`rosdep` is not meant to install source packages for you. It installs dependences of packages.

If you want to install `rviz` you should use `apt` such as `sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-rviz`